# Compute sum to n

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm confused as to how to finish answering this question.

Compute $$\sum_{i=28}^n (3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7^i})  $$

I end up with 
$$ 3[\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}] - 4[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}] + [\frac{k^n(5(-log(7))^n}{n!}]$$

I'm not entirely sure if the last part of my answer is right but my main question is what do I do about the $ i=28$? Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=28}^n \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7^i}\right) =\sum_{i=1}^n \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7^i}\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{27} \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7^i}\right) = 3\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right) - 4\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right) + 5\frac{\left((1-\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{n+1}\right)}{\frac{6}{7}}-\left(3\left(\frac{27(27+1)(2\cdot 27+1)}{6}\right) - 4\left(\frac{27(27+1)}{2}\right) + 5\frac{\left((1-\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{27+1}\right)}{\frac{6}{7}}\right) = \\ n^3-\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{3 n}{2}-\frac{(5\cdot 7^{-n})}{6}+\frac{35}{6} - \frac{1267186243758001135830923954}{65712362363534280139543}= \\ n^3-\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{3 n}{2}-\frac{(5\cdot 7^{-n})}{6}-\frac{7600817529865283115180659719}{394274174181205680837258}$$

Comment: So the final answer will always have n's left in it? I guess I just can't get around the final answer being a function of n.

Comment: $n$ is the superscript of the summation, in this context, $n$ is a placeholder for an **arbitrary** natural number that is greater than or equal to $28$. The above formula gives the summation for **any** upper limit number $n$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the awesome answer!

Comment: rubito: you're welcome. xD

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge28,$

$$\sum_{i=28}^n \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7^i}\right)  $$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7^i}\right) -\sum_{i=1}^{27} \left(3i^2 - 4i + \frac{5}{7^i}\right) $$

Now we can safely apply the formula you have specified

Comment: I see. So, considering my answer is correct, all I have to do take my answer with all the $ n's$ and substract the sum to 27? Is it acceptable for the final answer to contain n's?

Comment: @rubito, why not, otherwise how $$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$